# How can I execute a single query in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, keyboard-shortcuts, ssms

Background: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and I have a query window open that contains multiple queries.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will allow me to execute a single query without highlighting the query I would like to run first?  Some other SQL tools have shorcuts that run the query that is under the cursor, which keeps the hands on the keyboard, and away from the mouse.

Comment: I don't think Management Studio allows this, because then you would not be able to run multiple queries at once if the cursor was on any one of them, which could get annoying.

Comment: I feel that the opposite should be the case... as in... If I highlight multiple queries those queries highlighted would then run.  I'm just having so much trouble getting on board with the "Run all queries on page" automatically.  Having to individually highlight the 'single' query on a page consisting of many queries is just small annoyance and a waste of time having to highlight each time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I did some searching and was unable to find any keyboard shortcuts for executing individual lines in SSMS.  There is a reference online though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx

Personally I just highlight the row in question (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>, etc.) and hit <kbd>F5</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> works just as well on a Mac.

Comment: Ah well, it will have to do.  Thanks for take the time mmayo and everyone else!

Comment: Moving from Oracle after using SQL Developer for so long... this is a nuisance. I have to highlight every single query so I can run it without running all of the other queries I have on a single page?!?!... why does the semi-colon not allow me to run each query individually?  The semi-colon should be the stop point imho.  As in don't run queries after the semi-colon.

Answer (score 9):

The usual <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>PgDown</kbd> that apply to most or all Windows apps...

Then I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to execute

Comment: To clarify this a bit, you can use shift+uparrow, shift+downarrow to highlight the query you want, then Ctrl+E to execute it.  No mouse involved at all.

Answer (score 7):

Highlight the query you want to run, then <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: OP: "without highlighting the query I would like to run first"

Answer (score 6):

Since this was originally asked, DevArt has added this functionality to [their SSMS add-on](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/) . After installation, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> to execute the statement block under the cursor.

Comment: There is a free version, and it works for 2012, all the way up to 2016. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

With SSMS 2012 you can try [SSMS Executor](https://github.com/devvcat/ssms-executor) add-in.

Default shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't exactly what the OP was after, but here are two related tips that might help:

SSMS 2008 had a handy feature where you can double click the left margin (where the line numbers are) and it will auto-expand your selection to the beginning and end of the query that contains that line. So, double-click, f5.

It also had a nice feature which was, iirc, alt+up/down or maybe alt+shift+up/down, which will extend your selection to the beginning and end of line for each line you move the cursor across, including the one you started on, regardless of where your cursor is on the line. So this is another handy way to select the query you want to execute.

SSMS 2012 did away with those shortcuts (maybe they exist, but they're not the SAME, by default).

Comment: ctb is assuming line numbers are being displayed, this is the left margin being talked about. Since SSMS 2012 this feature has been lost. If you click (not double click) in the left margin (left from the line-numbers) you will toggle a breakpoint *and* make it look like the query is selected. Yet, when pressing F5, all the queries in the file will be executed!

Comment: No. There are 2 areas in the left margin. On the far left, there's a gray area for breakpoints, and immediately to the right of that, a white area where you can click and drag to highlight lines. Every code editor I know of does this. Yes, the white area gets bigger if you show line numbers, but it's still there even when they're off (colors could change, depending on theme).

Comment: Ah, thx for pointing that out. Still... it no longer works in 2016... too bad. Hope they fix it soon...

Answer (score 3):

I just mark the line I'm on (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>), and then click <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS **2008R2** with line numbers displayed, you can double-click a line number anywhere adjacent to a query to select the entire query that's part of that line.  It's a great feature and I use it all the time.

Unfortunately the feature was lost in the 2012 transition to the Visual Studio editor.  I created a [Connect issue for this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2578153), which I welcome votes on.

Comment: Nice to know, but when your hands are already on the keyboard, reaching for the mouse is much slower than `End`,`Shift`+`Home`; or `End`, `Shift`+`Up` + `Up` + `Up`.

Comment: @jpaugh You think so?

Answer (score 1):

A new version of SSMS is in development by Microsoft (kind of new version) it's called SQL Operations Studio.

With SOS (haha) you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, or — like me — replace the shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Management Studio don't have the feature to execute single SQL statement from the SQL script editor. even we create different shortcut still it doesn't work as we want.

I found a alterative for **SQL Server Management Studio** => [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/download/)
, community version is free.

1. Download DBeaver
2. Select SQL server option to connect
3. Download connector if not already installed(Auto suggest, popup will come)
4. Shortcut to execute SQL statement/Single line query ->  `Ctl + Enter`
5. To execute SQL script ->  `Alt + X`

Comment: DBeaver is also very good for multi-db environment.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl k + u will high lite text
f5 to run

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).